# How to customize the vertical scroll bar using jquery? Is that possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, scrollbar

Is that possible of customizing vertical scroll bar using Jquery and Css? If so help me out of this issue..

Thanks You

Comment: As scrollbar is an element native to each browser, you cannot directly  customize it. But many jquery plugins let you use your own custom scrollbar, just googleit

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143785/trying-to-make-a-custom-scroll-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you are into plugins, check out [this](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/). Here is a [demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html), but there are others.

Although I don't think it customizes browser's scrollbar (which cannot be customized), it alters the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

check this:
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

and this:
[customizing vertical scrollbar with css/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269131/customizing-vertical-scrollbar-with-css-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You asked the same question 1 hour ago. And in multiple answers the link to http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ was already given.

We will not write the actual code for you, that is your own job.